# Why is my Vue PWA offline faster than online?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3, workbox

using the most current version of Vue Cli 3 and the PWA feature enabled, I have noticed that our PWA is starting/booting way faster when the client is offline vs online. I was thinking that a internet connection could never slow down the boot time, as the service-worker would always first serve cached files and afterwards check for updates. For me, it is not obvious which default caching strategy for Workbox is implemented by the Vue Cli 3. The practical problem is, that none of our customers is turning on "offline/flight mode" on their phones, instead they just suffer from poor internet connection and thereby do not benefit from the offline capabilities of our App. It seems that the service-worker is not serving cached files unless the client is completely "offline". Boot times therefore are horrible...
Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Ive been on a meetup lately, there was a talk about SW in context of vue cli. I don't remember details but the guy said that vuecli's strategy is really poor and actually one should implement SW himself if wants to have any kind of a good experience.

Comment: Thanks for your input. For me its seems like all tutorials and demo Apps focus on "offline" vs online, but this approach is missing real-world situations. Clients are always in between.

Comment: Could be because of hundreds of different reasons. Like extensions that you have installed. Perhaps using the performance recorder in the chrome dev tools could give you some better insight. Also looking at the Network tab should help you wit seeing what is getting loaded from the cache.

Comment: @Mathias Thanks for the simple tip :) the performance recorder hinted me in the right direction. The reason was firebase.auth(), which is directly terminated when completely offline but not with poor connectivity. Due to the waiting of the firebase.auth() result, my app was stuck when having low connectivity.